# Writing QUery in Laravel with multiple conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to convert the below query in Laravel. Can somebody help:

```sql
select * 
from testtable 
where (pttid NOT IN 5 OR (pttid = 6 AND is != 1)) 
AND (sod BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-01' || updat BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `TestTable` model your query can be:

```
$result = TestTable::select(['*'])
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('pttid', 'NOT IN', 5);
        $q->orWhere(function($q2) {
            $q2->where('pttid', '=', 6);
            $q2->where('is', '!=', 1);
        });
    })->where(function ($q3) {
        $q3->whereBetween('sod', ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01']);
        $q3->orWhereBetween('updat', ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01']);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In a cleanest way do this:

- Create the `TestTable` model in this way:

Command

```
php artisan make:model TestTable
```

- After that In your controller invoke it through it's name

Code

```
use TestTable;
```

- Finally write your query in this way:

Code:

```
$data = TestTable::select('*')
            ->whereRaw("pttid NOT IN 5 OR (pttid = 6 AND is != 1)")
            ->whereBetween('sod', ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"])
            ->orWhereBetween('updat', ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"])
            ->get();
```

To filter dates use both methods: `whereBetween` and `orWhereBetween`.

> Always try to use models in spite of invoke the table name through `DB` facade bbecause this makes more difficult to mantain your code